# Unit test stateParams in controller test with Angular

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a basic controller that uses `$stateParams`.

```
angular.module('example')
  .controller('SampleCtrl', ['$stateParams',
      function($stateParams) {
         var vm = this;
         vm.isSomething = ($stateParams.isSomething === 'true') ? true : false;
      }
  ]);
```

In my unit test, I need to set the `$stateParams.isSomething` to true in one test, and false in another test.

```
 describe('SampleCtrl Test', function() {

    var ctrl, scope, $stateParams;

    // set default stateParams
    $stateParams = { isSomething: 'false' };

    beforeEach(function(){
       inject(function($rootScope, $controller){
          scope = $rootScope.$new();

          ctrl = $controller('SampleCtrl', {
            $scope: scope,
            $stateParams: $stateParams
          });
       });
    });

    describe('when isSomething is false', function() {
         it('should be false', function() {
            expect(ctrl.isSomething).toBe(false);
         });
    });

    describe('when isSomething is true', function() {

         beforeEach(function() {
           $stateParams.isSomething = 'true';
         });

         it('should be true', function() {
            // THIS IS FAILING
            expect(ctrl.isSomething).toBe(true);
         });
    });

 });
```

**How can I properly mock different states of `$stateParams` for different tests?**

Answer (score 6):

I think you would need to instantiate the controller again with the updated scope object.

You also have a few naming issues as well, see the comments in the code below.

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/NMNe1A98mwDmZgwobbmP?p=preview)

```
describe('SampleCtrl Test', function() {

    var ctrl, scope, $stateParams, $controller;

    // set default stateParams

    // you have called it 'something' in your controller not 'isSomething'
    $stateParams = { something: 'false' };

    beforeEach(function(){

      // load module
      module('example');


       inject(function($rootScope, _$controller_){
          scope = $rootScope.$new();

          // angular removes the _'s for you so you can call it $controller
          $controller = _$controller_;

          ctrl = $controller('SampleCtrl', {
            $scope: scope,
            $stateParams: $stateParams
          });
       });
    });

    describe('when isSomething is false', function() {
         it('should be false', function() {
            expect(ctrl.isSomething).toBe(false);
         });
    });

    describe('when isSomething is true', function() {

         beforeEach(function() {

           // you have called it 'something' in your controller not 'isSomething'
           $stateParams.something = 'true';

           // instantiate a new controller with the updated $stateParams object
           ctrl = $controller('SampleCtrl', {
              $scope: scope,
              $stateParams: $stateParams
            });

         });

         it('should be true', function() {
            // THIS IS FAILING
            expect(ctrl.isSomething).toBe(true);
         });
    });

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are having is that the beforeEach of the describe('when isSomething is true') evaluates *after* the beforeEach of the describe('SampleCtrl Test'), i.e. the controller is already instantiated when the $stateParams values are changed. As Matt wrote in his answer you need to instantiate the controller after the change has taken place.

I usually use a simple *workaround* to this. Since the beforeEach is instantiated after the controller, I usually write an empty it-statement wherein the incorrect stateParams were sent to the controller and ignore that one. For all preceeding it-statements the change to stateParams changes will have taken place and the controller will then use the correct variables:

```
describe('when isSomething is true', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
         $stateParams.isSomething = 'true';
    });

    it('should take one iteration to set the state parameter', function() {
        // do nothing as the controller will not use the new $stateParams yet
    });

    it('should be true', function() {
        // THIS IS NO LONGER FAILING
        expect(ctrl.isSomething).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

While not the most beautiful solution it seems to be the simplest